# Duda sobre el género de "bienhallado / a"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, género

Si yo soy un hombre y una mujer me dice "bienvenido", ¿respondo con "bienhallado" o con "bienhallada"?

Así mismo, si un hombre da la bienvenida a un grupo de mujeres, ¿deberían responder con "bienhallado" o con "bienhalladas"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Bienhallado" debe concordar con el género de la persona a quien se aplica:

- Si se aplica a una mujer debe usarse "bienhalla**da**".
- Si se aplica a un hombre debe usarse "bienhalla**do**".

Comment: ¡Gracias por la información!

Comment: Tienes alguna fuente que corrobore esto? podrías mejorar la respuesta aportando de donde sacas la información, incluso si solo es por experiencia a través de un uso repetido.

Comment: Es fácil: ¿Como estás? Estoy cansada o Estoy cansado. Además, es obvio que qualquier verbo debe de concordarr con el sujeto, hombre o mujer . ¿Para eso se necesita una fuente?

Answer (score 0):

Hay que tener en cuenta que si el grupo al que se da la bienvenida se compone de mujeres y hombres, aunque el número de mujeres sea bastate superior al de los hombres, se dice en masculino "bienvenidos" o "bien hallados". Si se desea ser políticamente correcto, entonces se mencionan ambos "bienvenidos y bienvenidas". Se pueden usar otras fórmulas para ser políticamente correcto sin caer en la duplicidad, como "le doy la bienvenida a todo el mundo" o "sed todos bienvenidos".